# ForgeRock Directory Server(OpenDj) ldapsearch in windows cmd ( not Linux)

Tags: ldap, openldap, opendj, forgerock

If I want to search an LDAP entry from a LDAP server using ForgeRock Directory Server(OpenDJ), the document says in Linux it works like the following.

```
$ ldapsearch \
 --hostname localhost \
--port 1389 \
--baseDn dc=example,dc=com \
"(cn=Abagail Abadines)" \
 cn mail street l
```

If I want to run this command in Windows, it doesn't seem to work. 
What do I need to change in this command to run it on Windows's cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same, you just need to use ldapsearch.bat, and use the Windows continuation character (`^`) instead of `\`, or put all arguments on a single line.

Also, when reading the documentation, the upper right corner icon allows you to copy the example command to your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after two hours of trying! I hope this might help someone. In Linux, \ means new line (of course, it also means **escape sequence**). It created new line. So in Window's **cmd** mode,  just type the whole command without \

Also, even in Linux, typing the whole command without \  seem to work fine without any error. (By putting \ every line somehow didn't work in the middle. )

In Unix/Linux, Windows, and Mac,   '/' (**slash**) and '\' ( **backslash** ) are confusing a little. So when executing commands or setting paths, gotta watch out.